# Is there a way to show Yoneda equality visually instead of compositional algebraic symbols?

Tags: category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma, hom-functor

The proof that $u \in F(A)$ is sufficient to define a natural transformation $\alpha : \text{Hom}(A, \cdot) \Rightarrow F(\cdot)$ goes like this:

Let $\alpha_X : g \in \text{Hom}(X, Y) \mapsto F(f)(u)$ where $u:= \alpha_A(\text{id}_A)$.  What we're trying to prove is:

$$
(\alpha_Y \circ g)(\xi) = ((Fg)\circ \alpha_X)(\xi)
,$$
forall $\xi \in \text{Hom}(A, X)$.  But this is $\Leftarrow$ by (via our definitions and functoriality, and associativity):

$$
\alpha_Y(g\circ \xi) = F(g\circ \xi)(u) = ((Fg) \circ (F\xi))(u) = \\ (Fg)\circ ((F\xi)(u)) = (Fg) \circ \alpha_X(\xi) = ((Fg)\circ \alpha_X)(\xi)
$$

Was wondering if that all can be compressed into one or a few diagrams (the implications of equality).  Above is what I call a compositional algebraic proof.  But I'm doing as much visual as I can in BananaCats (my app), so was just wondering...

Also what's it called when you promote an element of a hom-set to an actual morphism and vise versa?  Because the proof above implicitly used that fact in several places, yet we don't have a name for it?

Comment: The diagram [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma#Proof) is essentially the entirety of the proof. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your comment about "promoting an element of a hom-set to an actual morphism," because morphisms are (by definition) elements of hom-sets.

Comment: @Stahl see a previous post I made today in category theory.  That diagram is not the entirety of the proof if it took a line of 5 ='s to show that it's natural!  In other words your comment doesn't help.  When you represent an arrow you draw an arrow, when you represent an element of a set you do $x \in $ the set, two totally different things.  So my code will have to as you say understand that elements of hom-sets are morphisms and morphisms are elements of hom-sets.  While we do it automatically, a deterministic computer program has to be coded to do it.

Comment: @Stahl I will paint up what I mean and post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Half visual proof of Yoneda lemma]

Now here shows some features that my app should have including commutation color highlighting.

What your not seeing is the diagram of category $C$ on the left with $\text{Hom}(A, \cdot)$ and $F(\cdot)$ arrows going to this category diagram (essentially representing functors), the fact that most of the above diagram was drawn merely by seeding $C$ with $f$ and $g$ (as morphisms) and that when the user takes an element of $\text{Hom}(A, X)$ it shows up in $C$ or vise versa.

Comment: This is one of the most beautful pictures I have ever created in ms paint 3D 